# I Fetched Blog Data from api but it is showing only one Post So how can i show all data from api page 1

Tags: html, reactjs, json

Actually I fetched the Api for blog webpage but it showing only one blog post so I Need to show all Blog Posts from an Api on page 1 for my pagination for my frontend Webpage Sorry for my its kinda messy but can anyone help me  to fetch all data from the Api.

```
function Posts() {
  const { data: post, loading, error } = useFetch("https://accounts.com/api/blogs");

  if (loading) return <h1>Loading...</h1>;

  if (error) console.log(error);

  let postData = [];
  postData.push(post?.datas?.data);
  console.log(postData);

let showData = "";
  if (postData) {
    showData = (
      <>
        <div className="blogPost">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-4">
              <div className="post container px-5 pb-5">
                <div className="card-img-top">
                  <img
                    src={
                      "https://accounts.com/" +
                      postData.attachment?.media_url
                    }
                    alt="instagram-img"
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="card">
                  <div class="postBody">
                    <div className="postBodyinner pt-4 px-4 d-flex justify-content-between">
                      <h5 class="postTitle">{post?.datas?.data[0].title}</h5>
                      <h5 className="views"></h5>
                    </div>
                    <p class="card-desc">
                      {/* <Link to="/">{post?.datas?.data[0].content}</Link> */}
                    </p>
                    <div className="postBottom px-4 d-flex justify-content-between">
                      <p></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      {showData}
    </>
  );
}

export default Posts;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use dot map

```
const showData = data
.map(data => {
    return(
        <div  key={data.id}>
            <div className="blogPost">
               <div className="row">
        <div className="col-4">
          <div className="post container px-5 pb-5">
            <div className="card-img-top">
              <img
                src={
                  "https://bulkaccounts.com/" +
                  postData.attachment?.media_url
                }
                alt="instagram-img"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="card">
              <div class="postBody">
                <div className="postBodyinner pt-4 px-4 d-flex justify-content-between">
                  <h5 class="postTitle">{post?.datas?.data[0].title}</h5>
                  <h5 className="views"></h5>
                </div>
                <p class="card-desc">
                  {/* <Link to="/">{post?.datas?.data[0].content}</Link> */}
                </p>
                <div className="postBottom px-4 d-flex justify-content-between">
                  <p></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
        </div>
    )
})

return (
<>
  {showData}
</>
)
```